# How to redirect process output to System.String

Tags: c#, .net, process, console, response.redirect

I am calling Java process from .NET application and I need to redirect console output
to System.String to do some later parsing. Please advice. I would appreciate short code example.

```
public bool RunJava(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.EnvironmentVariables.Add("VARIABLE1", "1");
        psi.FileName = "JAVA.exe";
        psi.Arguments = "-Xmx256m jar.name";

        Process.Start(psi);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A better way will be to create a `Process` instance and capture the output using a stream like this:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "JAVA.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xmx256m jar.name";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("VARIABLE1", "1");
cmd.Start();

StreamReader sr = cmd.StandardOutput;
string output = sr.ReadToEnd();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to set [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) to true, and then the easiest way of getting the results is to use the event-driven mechanism:

```
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
p.BeginOutputReadLine(LineHandler);
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

where `LineHandler` is an appropriate method to collect each line of output, e.g. into a `StringWriter`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Will give it a try. Will update my question as soon as new issues come up.

Answer (score 2):

Set 
 `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` 
and
 `.RedirectStandardError`. 
 Then you can read the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError`-streams on the Process-object that is returned from `Process.Start`.

MSDN have a nice and simple sample for you.