# how to redirect cmnd output

Tags: c#, process

I want to start a cmd file and redirect the output to the console, but it doesn't work. What I have to do? I already set  `startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true`.

```
com = "Parameter";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = 
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo+ @"\Make\copy.cmd";
startInfo.Arguments = com;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
output = process.StandardOutput;
string ln;

while ((ln = output.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829749/how-to-redirect-process-output-to-system-string?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx)

Set `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`

Then you can get the output as

```
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I get an error. You can't set startInfo.UseShellExecute = true; and startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Comment: Sorry - my bad - ShellExecute should be set to false for redirecting STD Output.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have this solution:

```
                com = "Parameter";;

                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo + @"\Make\copy.cmd";
                startInfo.Arguments = com;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
                Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
```